# How to fetch content from namespace "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.HelperResult"

Tags: razor, asp.net-core

In `ASP.NET Core`, I need to fetch the content value from the namespace `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.HelperResult` and assign the value in a variable but its assigning the namespace to that variable.

It works fine in `MVC` when i use namespace `System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult` and assign that content to variable. (Content are some html elements).

Please, check the picture to find the issue.

My code:

[Variable with namespace name as value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnbAZ.png)

Comment: How is your question related to `git`, `github`, and `gitlab` tags?

Answer (score 0):

In `.NET Core` `HelperResult` returns [`IHtmlContent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razor.helperresult) instead of [`IHtmlString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpages.helperresult(v=vs.111).aspx).

For `IHtmlContent` it might be convenient to use an extension like the one mentioned [here](https://github.com/aspnet/HtmlAbstractions/issues/35):

```
public static IHtmlContent GetList(this IHtmlHelper helper)
{
    var listHtml = new HtmlContentBuilder();
    listHtml.AppendHtml("<ol><li>");
    listHtml.AppendHtml(helper.ActionLink("foo", "bar", "example"));
    listHtml.AppendHtml("</li></ol>");
    return listHtml;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (since `HelperResult` implements `IHtmlContent` interface):

```
    public static string ToHtmlString(this IHtmlHelper source, IHtmlContent htmlContent)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        using (TextWriter tw = new StringWriter(sb))
        {
            var encoder = (HtmlEncoder)source.ViewContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(HtmlEncoder));
            htmlContent.WriteTo(tw, encoder);
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

and call this method in your Razor view like this:

```
@Html.ToHtmlString(helperResultObject)
```